# Retrofit ScalarsConverterFactory.create() doesn't effect to error "Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to get request from a currency API and it's Json type is like this.

```
{
"eur":{
  "code":"EUR",
  "alphaCode":"EUR",
  "numericCode":"978",
  "name":"Euro",
  "rate":0.99540765179992,
  "date":"Tue, 12 Jul 2022 23:55:01 GMT",
  "inverseRate":1.00461353516
},
```

Here is the link of JSON http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json

Even I try some solutions on here I couldn't effect to that error below

> Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Here is my RetrofitInstance class.

```
abstract class RetrofitInstance {
companion object {
    var gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .build()


    val retrofitInstance: RetrofitApi by lazy {
        retrofit.create(RetrofitApi::class.java)
    }

}
}
```

I tried ScalarsConverterFactory.create() but it didn't effect.So what can I else try to get request?

```
BASE_URL="http://www.floatrates.com/"
```

and my interface is like below

```
interface RetrofitApi {
    @GET("daily/usd.json")
    suspend fun getUserData(): Currency
}
```

and my ViewModel is like this:

```
    private const val TAG = "Currency View Model"
class CurrencyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private var _currencies = MutableLiveData<Currency>()
    val users: LiveData<Currency>
        get() = _currencies

    fun getData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _currencies.value = RetrofitInstance.retrofitInstance.getUserData()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

In my model package,my data classes are like this:

```
data class Currency(
    val eur: Eur,
    val gbp: Gbp
)
```

Euro

```
data class Eur(
    val alphaCode: String,
    val code: String,
    val date: String,
    val inverseRate: Double,
    val name: String,
    val numericCode: String,
    val rate: Double
)
```

GBP

```
data class Gbp(
    val alphaCode: String,
    val code: String,
    val date: String,
    val inverseRate: Double,
    val name: String,
    val numericCode: String,
    val rate: Double
)
```

Comment: share your Currency model

Comment: I added the content of my Currency model.

Comment: If your model have multi object like "eur", then your model should have started with JSONArray not the object, With [] this, that is where you are facing issue.

Comment: I am not good at using retrofit.Just found a retrofit connection like this so I haven't any idea what should do about it :(